# Where have my 8 rep points gone on AU? It was 900 , now it is only 892?

Tags: discussion

I had answered a question rightly, **I dont know why was my answer downvoted 4 times and I got -8 rep,** and the question has also been removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably referring to [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595557/a-program-of-mine-wants-to-run-as-root-how-do-i-do-this) which has now been removed:

### maths

To understand the 8 point issue - you had been upvoted once on your answer hence gained 10 rep points.

You have also been downvoted once - thus lost 2 rep points giving a sum of 8 rep points gained.

### cleanup

Community - the StackExchange robo-cleaner - has decided to delete the question:

- The combination of the question itself having answers with negative votes, no accepted answer, the question being closed and a question which has been negatively voted at some point.

These factors are amongst its main criteria to delete stuff.

Community does this to keep the site clean - the question, nor answers are no longer deemed worthy to keep around.

### net-sum

Thus when a question is deleted - through Community, owner activity,  site-user activity - any rep gained within the last 3 months is automatically removed as well.

Comment: I later guessed that rep decreased since question was removed but i had posted the question then, Anyway thank you!